# Restarting an asp.net core app with IIS doesnt actually restart the app properly as program.cs doesnt execute

Tags: asp.net-core, iis-7.5

I have deployed an asp.net core web app to an AWS Server running windows and IIS from azure devops. All the app code has updated, the dlls etc had updated but the new code that kickstarts serilog doesnt run.

This is because program.cs/startup.cs have not executed, it's as if the app updated but kept running withoout restarting.

Restarting the app in IIS or doing a full IIS reset, or restarting the IIS app pool does nothing. The app is running on port 80.

If I open powershell and type "dotnet myapp.dll" then the logs appear! because program.cs executed but that starts another instance on a different port and is nothing to do with IIS.

How do you properly restart a .net core app with IIS that actually makes it start up again?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is all because IIS didnt have permissions to write to the log folder.. lol. All ok now.